# SYMFONY Serializer - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Tags: php, mysql, serialization, symfony4

I'm trying to setup my Symfony 4.3 project in local machine (MAC OS - MAMP 4 - php 7.2 - mysql 5.6) but I have an error on serialization. This error does not exist in the production site.

Data is inserted with doctrine fixtures.

Here some details:

[Serializer exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJpkJ.png)

[The cause of the exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lxnwb.png) (The ? symbol)

[Doctrine configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxu5O.png)

[Mysql table configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hh11A.png)

Hope you can help me

Comment: You're using French, right?

Comment: Exacly, there are characters like é and è. It does work on production site but not in dev. The configuration is the same, i don't understand ...

Comment: Sharing actual stacktrace of that error would be more than just some images that you share...

Also you should start with 4.4, just because 4.3 has just security fixes until `July 2020` - https://symfony.com/releases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the OP pointed out the problem was happening when using the `strtolower` function.

Quoting from the [documentation](https://www.php.net/strtolower):

> `strtolower ( string $string ) : string`
>
> Returns string with all alphabetic characters converted to lowercase.
>
> Note that 'alphabetic' is determined by the current locale. This means that e.g. in the default "C" locale, characters such as umlaut-A (Ä) will not be converted.

---

To fix this, you could:

- **Option 1:** Set the "correct" locale for your use case.
- **Option 2:** Use [`mb_strtolower`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php)

---

**About `mb_strtolower`:**

> By contrast to strtolower(), 'alphabetic' is determined by the Unicode character properties. Thus the behaviour of this function is not affected by locale settings and it can convert any characters that have 'alphabetic' property, such as A-umlaut (Ä).

Depending on your usecase/setup, the second way might not be the best way for you to use, since:

1. You need to install/enable [Multibyte String](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php)
2. It's MUCH [slower](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1d4d62d014cf1cd4c846be51f7b883962f38a3b0), than the `strtolower` function

Answer (score 0):

The problem was coming from the strtolower function. The result is "Hélène" wihout strtolower and b"hã©lã¨ne" with the strtolower.

use mb-strtolower instead php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php

Comment: If that's the problem, you could just use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php, which should solve it